# How to add my div to poptrox popup image?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, popup

I need to put my html  below the window with image.
How can I do this?

Thanks!

```
$main.poptrox({
        onPopupOpen: function() { $body.addClass('is-poptrox-visible'); },
        onPopupClose: function() { $body.removeClass('is-poptrox-visible'); },
        overlayColor: '#1a1f2c',
        overlayOpacity: 0.75,
        popupCloserText: '',
        popupLoaderText: '',
        selector: '.item.thumb a.image',
        caption: function($a) {
            return $a.prev('h2').html();
        },
        usePopupDefaultStyling: false,
        usePopupCloser: false,
        usePopupCaption: true,
        usePopupNav: true,
        windowMargin: 50
    });
```

[image]

How and where is this div class="poptrox-popup" created? How can I supplement this node or fill it with my own content? There is no such node anywhere in the html. The parmeters that are passed to poptrox({ do not give me this opportunity.

[image]

Comment: What have you tried and what results did you get?

Comment: I tried using the caption: function($a) function {
return $a.prev('h2').html();
}, but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem myself (html layout). Also solved the issue with html-->cshtml via return PartialView("_Themes"); The question is closed!
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zLW4e.png)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).